# Celery result backend stores a encoded string in result column

Tags: serialization, redis, celery, django-celery

After I run an async task

```
tasks.add.apply_async( (10, 10))
```

I checked the result backends database table *celery_taskmeta* and noticed the result containing something like *gAJLBC4=*

I couldn't find in the docs what that result implies and whether I can store the actual result of the function call ( ie, the return value ) in the table *as is*.

For this instance where I am executing a task which adds two numbers : 10 and 10 , the **result** column in **celery_taskmeta** should have 20 as per my understanding ( which is probably wrong ) .

How should I achieve that ?

I'm assuming that result is also serialized?  I'm using a redis broker and not clear which configuration I need to set to be able to retrieve the actual return value.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to get the result is not to query the database directly and instead to use the [result api](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results)

```
result = tasks.add.apply_async( (10, 10))
result.ready
> True
result.result
> 20
```

Comment: Thanks, But isn't that blocking the flow?

Comment: I mean, that's not async.

Comment: ! - it's been 5 months! and no, it is not blocking the flow. please read the celery documentation and do some experimentation with test tasks to see how this works.

Comment: Thanks. OK, I will reframe my answer. To use .ready and then .result I would need to be monitor the status of the task in a different thread, and then manually insert the result into the database. I was looking for an out-of-the-box way to store the result in the database.

Comment: please ask a new question.